# Desabilitar maximizar e minimizar de windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf

Preciso uma solução para desabilitar os botões de maximizar e minimizar de um windows form. Utilizando WPF esses dois atributos resolveriam:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
```

Mas agora preciso que seja num windows form. Segue a imagem abaixo de como ficou em form em WPF.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use as seguintes propriedades da *Form*:

```
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
form1.MaximizeBox = false;
form1.MinimizeBox = false;
```

`form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;` é necessário para evitar que a janela seja redimensionada com o rato, arrastando a borda.

Comment: Excelente. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

O formulário tem duas propriedades que chamam MaximizeBox e MinimizeBox, é só setar para false:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Excelente. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Existem várias formas de se chegar nesse resultado:
Se você quer desabilitar apenas os botões de minimizar e maximizar, pode usar as propriedades `MaximizeBox`e `MinimizeBox`:

Se as mesmas estão com o valor `true`:

[image: MaximizeBox e MinimizeBox em True]

Se as mesmas estão com o valor `false`:

[image: MaximizeBox e MinimizeBox em False]

Ou então utilizar da propriedade `ControlBox`, que quando false retira todo o conteúdo do cabeçalho (Exceto o titulo do mesmo):

[image: ControlBox em false]

Comment: Excelente. Muito obrigado!